# How to make a stacked Font Awesome icon have the same width as a fixed width non stacked one?

Tags: css, font-awesome

http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/aZ9g4/3/

The stacked "GitHub Issue" icon is twice as large as the other fixed width non stacked ones, and makes my nav look bad.

Is there a way within the library to make it be the same size without hacking low level CSS properties?

If only there was a `fa-stack-half`...

If not, what is the best workaround?

Comment: One trick I used (it's a bit of a hack sadly) is to use a negative margin on one side of the icons.

Comment: …ended up just getting rid of the stack and using a background + border-radius (needed a rounded square as background.) Makes life easier.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the [examples for stacked icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), you can do this by modifying the font-size on the span:

Just add a rule like:

```
.fa-sm {
    font-size:0.63em;
}
```

With Markup:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
</span>Github Issue
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epxtY/

Comment: btw the closest issue for this is https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2815 if you want to subscribe.

Comment: This no solve the problem when use two or more icons with and without stack, can not resize all icons to same size, you can use two custom separated classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try adding this CSS

.fa-stack{
    width: 1.28571em;    
}
.fa-circle-o.fa-stack-2x {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    top: 2px;
}
.fa-exclamation.fa-stack-1x{
    font-size: 10px;
    top: -3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9g4/12/

Comment: Thank you @mechanicals, but is there an advantage of this approach over the one proposed by Kerry, considering that his one uses more code?

Comment: Nothing special really, but you'll still need to add some extra CSS to the Kerry's code to adjust the inner exclamation icon which looks out of alignment in Kerry's JS fiddle.

Comment: You are right, at first I hadn't noticed that it is was not very well aligned.

Comment: If you look at the original 1x and 2x icons stacked on top of each other they aren't aligned either. Scaling them smaller just makes this more prominent ;)